# new Array() or [ ] ; new Object() or { }

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create an empty object in JavaScript with {} or new Object()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251402/create-an-empty-object-in-javascript-with-or-new-object)

Is there any benefits of using `new Array()` or `[ ]` ?
The same question about `new Object()` and `{ }`.