# javascript object composition syntax

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

In the following code, I want to be able to call bindClickEvents() like so:

```
App.Utils.Modal.bindClickEvents();
```

However, I don't understand the syntax necessary to do this.

Current code:

```
var App = new Object;

App.Modal = {
  bindClickEvents: function() {
    return $('a.alert-modal').click(function(e) {
      return console.log('Alert Callback');
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  return App.Modal.bindClickEvents();
});
```

Comment: Always use `{}` instead of `new Object`

Comment: why is that if u don't mind me asking?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251402/create-an-empty-object-in-javascript-with-or-new-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one go:

```
var App = {
  Modal : {
    bindClickEvents : function () {/* ... */}
  }
}
```

or if you want to break that up to separate steps:

```
var App = {};
App.Modal = {};
Modal.bindClickEvents = function () {/* ... */};
```

BTW, in reference to your original question title, this is not object chaining. This is object composition. Object chaining is being able to call methods in an object multiple times in a single statement.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
var App = {};

App.Utils = {};

App.Utils.Modal = {
  bindClickEvents: function() {
    return $('a.alert-modal').click(function(e) {
      return console.log('Alert Callback');
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  return App.Utils.Modal.bindClickEvents();
});
```

Comment: I guess OP didn't *actually* want a Utils object in there :-)

Answer (score 0):

Prefer the object literal syntax to the Object constructor; some authors go so far as to call the latter an anti-pattern

Here's the simplest way to set up `App.Utils.Modal.bindClickEvents();`

```
var App = {
      Utils: {
           Modal: {
               bindClickEvents: function() {
                    return $('a.alert-modal').click(function(e) {
                        return console.log('Alert Callback');
                    });
               }
           }
      }
 };
```

Or you can piece it together one step at a time:

```
var App = {};
App.Utils = {};
App.Utils.Modal = {};
App.Utils.Modal.bindClickEvents = function() {
    return $('a.alert-modal').click(function(e) {
      return console.log('Alert Callback');
    });
};
```