# Javascript new keyword usage

Tags: javascript, object, new-operator

Is there a difference between calling a javascript function with or without the new keyword? For instance if I had the function:

```
function computer(){
  this.hardDrive = "big";
  this.processor = "fast";
}
```

and I then call it in two different ways:

```
var hp = computer();
var hp = new computer();
```

what is going to be the difference between the two function calls?

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) and [Is JavaScript's new keyword considered harmful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful) and [Using Object.create instead of new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new)

Comment: See also [Create an empty object in JavaScript with {} or new Object()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251402/create-an-empty-object-in-javascript-with-or-new-object).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without `new`, `this` refers to the global object, and not any object returned from the function.

If you were to execute your code, you'd find that the first `hp` would be `undefined`, whereas the second would be `[object Object]`. Further, for obvious reasons, the first would not have a property of `hardDrive` or `processor`, but the second would.

In the first example, your two properties would have been added to the `window` object.

Comment: isn't it that the `this` in the first case (no `new`) is the `window` global object? and executing the function adds `hardDrive` and `processor` to the global object?

Comment: Not at all. ECMA-262 defines [execution context](http://es5.github.com/#x10.3), it is the only context in which the word is used. An execution context consists of all the local variables, parameters, scope chain, etc. and includes *this*. The value that *this* is set to by the call has nothing at all to do with the execution context that the call was made from, or the function context that is created by a call. All you know is that in global code, *this* references the global object. In any other context, it can reference (almost) anything, including the global object.

Answer (score 1):

The first one, not using `new`, will run with `this` referring to the window object.  The second one, using `new`, will create a new empty object, and that object will be the `this` within the function.