# Javascript arrays and JQuery .param

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, param

I've noticed something weird.  I've always thought `new Array()` was the same as `{}`, however it seems to be different as `{}` seems to just be an object type whereas `new Array()` is an Array in the Chrome debugger.

So I've been using `$.param(data)`, where data is the data from a `$.ajax()` call.  I notice that when i have a `params1 = new Array()` and a `params2 = {}` inside the data, they come out differently.

params1 becomes

```
params1[]=1&params1[]=2
```

and params2 becomes

```
params2[0]=1&params2[1]=2.
```

The problem is that I had been using `.param(data, false)` because I noticed that `params1[]` was being serialized incorrectly, however `.param(data, false)` fails for `params2` and gives me `params2=[object+Object]`.

I figure I can get around this by just using .param(data) and stripping out "[]" so that regardless of it being initialized using `{}` or `new Array`, it'll still work out correctly.  But I'd like to know if there's a better solution (short of always using `{}` vs `new Array`).

Comment: `[]` is shorthand for creating a new JavaScript array, not `{}`. As you already saw, `{}` creates an empty object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an empty object in JavaScript with {} or new Object()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251402/create-an-empty-object-in-javascript-with-or-new-object)

Answer (score 1):

Kyliod,

In javascript {} is shorthand for creating a new Object, and [] is shorthand for a "new Array()."

SO:

```
var myArray1 = [];
var myArray2 = new Array();
var myObject = {};
myObject.objVariable1 = 'some string or other variable data';
var myObject2 = { obj2Var1 : 'some string', obj2Var2 : 1234, obj2Var3 : true };

// do stuff

var thing1 = myArray1[1]; // get something out of myArray1
var thing2 = myArray2[2]; // get something out of myArray2
var thing3 = myObject.objVariable1; // get something out of myObject
if(myObject2.obj2Var3)
{
  // do other stuff
}
```

Hopefully this helps you clear up your jQuery / javascript Ajax issues.