# What means {} in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was researching some sample code and couldn't understand this line of code

```
var foo = {};
```

As far as i could see it is used as a kind of arry where the index is a string entered by the user instead of 0,1,2,... etc. Can explain/confirm this.
Cheers!

Comment: For future reference, those are referred to as `curly braces`.

Comment: @AshleyDavies I always thought they were smiley mustaches. ;)

Comment: I guess that's one way of looking at them! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an object literal. It can be used like an associate array in other languages, but javascript objects tend to do much more. It does use key/value pairs, but the values can be functions, other objects, arrays or anything.

Answer (score 1):

declaring a javascript variable as {} is basically creating an empty object.

See this answer: [Create an empty object in JavaScript with {} or new Object()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251402/create-an-empty-object-in-javascript-with-or-new-object)

Answer (score 0):

{} represents an empty object.

To initialize an object you can do something like this:

```
var foo = {
    bar: "test";
}

alert(foo.bar); // alerts "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the notation for creating an empty object and assigning it to foo.

The 'array' like behavior is that JavaScript objects act like associative arrays - mappings between strings and properties, which can be Numbers, String, etc. or other Objects.

I suggest you read "JavaScript The Good Parts"