# How to prevent references from a constructed object back into a blueprint like source object which got assigned to the former target structure?

Tags: javascript, reference, clone, factory, deep-copy

This is an example from a Pokemon-like game. I am constructing an Object, and inside it i am trying to make a new Object "en" and "to", that is two different attacks. The problem is that when i try to edit something in either of the attack Objects ("en" and "two"), the change happens to every Pokemon with the same name. This doesn't happen with the "health", so i think that the `this.en = new Object;` is the problem.

This is the code for constructing the Pokemon

```
function Fakemon(_navn, _type, _attackPower, _src,
    _1Navn, _1Force, _1Antall_, _2Navn, _2Force, _2Antall) {
    this.navn = _navn;
    this.type = _type;
    this.attackPower = _attackPower;
    this.src = _src;

    this.en = new Object;
    this.en.navn = _1Navn;
    this.en.force = _1Force;
    this.en.antall = _1Antall_;

    this.to = new Object;
    this.to.navn = _2Navn;
    this.to.force = _2Force;
    this.to.antall = _2Antall;

    this.health = 1000;

    console.log(this.en);
    this.pushFakemon = function() {
        fakemonSamling.push(this);
    }
    this.pushFakemon();
}

const fakemon1 = new Fakemon("BatCat", "Flying", [10, 50], ["batFront.png", "batBack.png"], "Blood Suck", [25, 38, 60], 10, "Wing Slap", [10, 17, 25], 20);
const fakemon2 = new Fakemon("Muffin Time", "Normal", [15, 45], ["cupcakeFront.png", "cupcakeBack.png"], "Frosting cover", [10, 17, 25], 20, "Cake stomp", [40, 50, 60], 5);
```

This is the Code for putting three Pokemon's to each player

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var temp1 = new Object;
        player1.push(Object.assign(temp1, randomFakemon()));
        var temp2 = new Object;
        player2.push(Object.assign(temp2, randomFakemon()));
    }
```

Comment: can you share the code you use when you "try to edit something in either of the attack Objects" ?

Comment: No, the problem is not in your constructor. Rather it's that `randomFakemon()` can return the *same* fakemon multiple times, instead of creating a new one every time.

Comment: Btw, [using `new Object` is rather unidiomatic, prefer object literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/251402/1048572)

Comment: Another thought ... in case the OP can not express the intention of a function, especially constructor function, with maybe up to 3 or 4 parameters the OP might think about using 1 to 3 config objects as parameters. For the OP's use case even more so as all the arguments just get assigned as public properties ... think about `Object.assign(this, configA, { en: ...configB, to: ...configC });`

Comment: ... code review part 2 ... the implementation of `pushFakemon` method (either own or prototypal) is dispensable. Instead push the newly created instance directly.

Comment: 3/4 ... also, and _Bergi_ already touched the subject, in case `randomFakemon()` returns randomly **references** from the fakemon collection called `fakemonSamling` does `Object.assign` not protect these references from further mutations. On the other other hand, assigning a true `Fakemon` instance via `Object.assign` to another (even empty) object makes the latter not a `Fakemon` instance. It will remain a shallow copy, an object which holds references to deeper nested properties of its `Fakemon` instance source object.

Comment: 4/4 ... And making use of [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) does not solve the problem either for one would loose the anyway dispensable `pushFakemon` method. Thus the question arises ... What is the constructor good for. There are neither prototypal methods nor subclassing involved. My final suggestion is ... _"Use a fakemon factory"_.

Comment: Using structuredClone worked, thanks :)

Comment: _"Using structuredClone worked"_ ... There must have been some other changes as well. Invoking `structuredClone` will fail (throw an exception) with instances of the OP's original `Fakemone` constructor function due to the method implementation of `pushFakemon`.

Comment: I did change `this.pushFakemon = function() {
        fakemonSamling.push(this);
    }
    this.pushFakemon();`, to`fakemonSamling.push(this);`. I only changed it because i did not need it, turns out i would not work otherwise, as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the OP has/had problems with two of the design choices.

`player1.push(Object.assign(temp1, randomFakemon()));` ... picks a random true `Fakemon` instance from the OP's fakemon collection.

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) treats the source like an ordinary object. It assigns just the source object's enumerable own properties to the target object. Thus, nested, **non** [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) properties still will hold references to their's sources. The target object also will not change its type. It will not all of a sudden be an instance of `Fakemon`.

The just described problem can be solved with a reliable own implementation of a `clone` function or, if available, by a  [structured clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone).

With the cloning approach a constructor, though it create own types, but does neither extend/subclass nor implement prototypal methods, renders useless.

The only (own) method from the OP's example code is dispensable anyway, thus the suggested solution is a ***code refactoring*** towards a ***fakemon factory*** function and the usage of ***`clone` functionality***.

```js
function createFakemon(base, attack1, attack2) {
  const fakemon = Object.assign({
      health: 1000,
    }, base, {
      en: { ...attack1 },
      to: { ...attack2 },
    });
  fakemonCollection.push(fakemon);

  return fakemon;
};
const fakemonCollection = []; // Dansk: fakemon samling.

function getRandomFakemon() {
  return fakemonCollection[
    Math.floor(Math.random() * fakemonCollection.length)
  ];
}

const cloneDataStructure = (
  ('function' === typeof structuredClone) && structuredClone ||
  (value => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)))
);

const fakemon1 = createFakemon({
  navn: 'BatCat',
  type: 'Flying',
  attackPower: [10, 50],
  sources: ['batFront.png', 'batBack.png'],
}, {
  navn: 'Blood Suck',
  force: [25, 38, 60],
  antall: 10,
}, {
  navn: 'Wing Slap',
  force: [10, 17, 25],
  antall: 20,
});
const fakemon2 = createFakemon({
  navn: 'Muffin Time',
  type: 'Normal',
  attackPower: [15, 45],
  sources: ['cupcakeFront.png', 'cupcakeBack.png'],
}, {
  navn: 'Frosting cover',
  force: [10, 17, 25],
  antall: 20,
}, {
  navn: 'Cake stomp',
  force: [40, 50, 60],
  antall: 5,
});

// create a(ny) player's fakemon as true clone
// of a randomly picked `fakemonCollection` item.
const playerFakemon = cloneDataStructure(
  getRandomFakemon()
);
// change a single attack value.
playerFakemon.en.navn = 'Foo Bar';
/*
  Thus instead of ...

  player1.push(Object.assign(temp1, randomFakemon()));

  ... one now would do ...

  player1.push(cloneDataStructure(getRandomFakemon()));
*/
console.log({
  // no mutation at any of the collection's fakemon items.  
  fakemonCollection,
  // single different value for `playerFakemon.en.navn`.
  playerFakemon,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This a better approach than mine, but changing Object.assign to structuredClone did the job.

Comment: @KristianGjertsen ... _"changing Object.assign to structuredClone did the job"_ ... I doubt that. There definitely were some other changes too. Invoking `structuredClone` will fail (throw an exception) with instances of the OP's original `Fakemone` constructor function due to the method implementation of `pushFakemon`.